# Drying Up Very Similar Implementations of an Interface

Tags: c#, object-oriented, interface, rubberduck

Work continues on the [Rubberduck VBA Editor Add-in](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck). I have a need to call some VBA code from the add-in with `Application.Run`. Unfortunately, the `Application` part of that refers to the particular Office Application that is hosting the VBA editor. So, if I'm working in Excel, `Application` refers to the instance of Excel (Word, Access, etc.). Unfortunately, these do not share a common interface, so I wrapped them up in one of my own so I could use them interchangeably.

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public interface IHostApplication
{
    void Run(string target);
    long TimedMethodCall(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName);
}
```

Which is great, because now I can call VBA's `Application.Run` method without caring which Office Application is hosting the VBA Editor.

```
duration =_hostApp.TimedMethodCall( _projectName, _moduleName, _methodName);
```

The problem is my implementations of `IHostApplication` are all very similar. Like, *copy/paste* similar. I considered a base class, but don't see how that could work with all of the Application objects being a different type. Maybe some delegate "magic" would help me out here??

**ExcelApp:**

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class ExcelApp : IHostApplication
{
    Excel.Application _application;
    public ExcelApp()
    {
        _application = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }

    ~ExcelApp()
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_application);
    }

    public void Run(string target)
    {
        _application.Run(target);
    }

    /// <summary>   Timed call to Application.Run </summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="projectName">  Name of the project containing the method to be run. </param>
    /// <param name="moduleName">   Name of the module containing the method to be run. </param>
    /// <param name="methodName">   Name of the method run. </param>
    ///
    /// <returns>   Number of milliseconds it took to run the VBA procedure. </returns>
    public long TimedMethodCall(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //excel can have multiple projects, so it supports fully quantified names
        _application.Run(string.Concat(projectName, ".", moduleName, ".", methodName));

        stopwatch.Stop();

        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

**AccessApp**

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class AccessApp : IHostApplication
{
    Access.Application _application;
    public AccessApp()
    {
        _application = (Access.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");
    }

    ~AccessApp()
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_application);
    }

    public void Run(string target)
    {
        _application.Run(target);
    }

    /// <summary>   Timed call to Application.Run </summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="projectName">  Name of the project containing the method to be run. </param>
    /// <param name="moduleName">   Name of the module containing the method to be run. </param>
    /// <param name="methodName">   Name of the method run. </param>
    ///
    /// <returns>   Number of milliseconds it took to run the VBA procedure. </returns>
    public long TimedMethodCall(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //access supports only single project; I would think it could handle Module.Procedure syntax, but it blows up with a com exception if I try.
        _application.Run(methodName);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

**WordApp:**

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class WordApp : IHostApplication
{
    Word.Application _application;
    public WordApp()
    {
        _application = (Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    }

    ~WordApp()
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_application);
    }

    public void Run(string target)
    {
        _application.Run(target);
    }

    /// <summary>   Timed call to Application.Run </summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="projectName">  Name of the project containing the method to be run. </param>
    /// <param name="moduleName">   Name of the module containing the method to be run. </param>
    /// <param name="methodName">   Name of the method run. </param>
    ///
    /// <returns>   Number of milliseconds it took to run the VBA procedure. </returns>
    public long TimedMethodCall(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //Word supports single projects only
        _application.Run(string.Concat(moduleName, ".", methodName));

        stopwatch.Stop();

        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider using an generic abstract base class.

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public abstract class HostApplicationBase<TApplication> : IHostApplication
{
    protected readonly TApplication _application;
    protected HostApplicationBase(string applicationName)
    {
        _application = (TApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(applicationName + ".Application");
    }

    ~HostApplicationBase()
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_application);
    }

    public abstract void Run(string target);
    protected abstract string GenerateFullyQualifiedName(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName);

    public long TimedMethodCall(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Run(GenerateFullyQualifiedName(projectName, moduleName, methodName));

        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

The Excel application would then be implemented as follows:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class ExcelApp : HostApplicationBase<Excel.Application>
{
    public ExcelApp() : base("Excel") { }

    public override void Run(string target)
    {
        base._application.Run(target);
    }

    protected override string GenerateFullyQualifiedName(string projectName, string moduleName, string methodName)
    {
        return string.Concat(projectName, ".", moduleName, ".", methodName);
    }
}
```

You could get rid of the abstract methods by using `Action`s, but there is really no great difference. Now only the `Run`-method will look the same for all applications. You could get rid of this using reflection.

(As a side-note: Scala would offer you structural typing in that case, which AFAIK will use reflection internally.)

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I'm looking for, but what does Scala have to do with it? We're developing this in C#...

Comment: It was just a side-note. (-;

Answer (score 1):

Every implementation of `IHostApplication` is expected to have a reference to a COM object as a member. Therefore, it should really extend `IDisposable`, because all of it's implementers should really be implementing the `IDisposable` interface. It's really not good to be letting the release of the COM object up to a finalizer that may never run at all.